# How to install Luz?

Tags: 13.04, luz

How would I install [Luz](http://gnomecoder.wordpress.com/luz/) on Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: So the github doesn't work? https://github.com/lighttroupe/luz

Comment: Lol no. I tried building from source, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the author's website:

> Luz still doesn’t run on 11.10 **or newer**, due to [lp:850734](https://bugs.launchpad.net/luz/+bug/850734), so
>   you’ll need an 11.04 system.

So I don't think you'll be able to install it. Sorry.

Good luck!

Comment: comment #5 claims you can ;)

Comment: Yes it does but it clearly states: "I somehow got it to work on 12.04" and the details seems too narrow. If it barely will work on 12.04 I don't think it will succeed in 13.04  but thank you for pointing that.